# Not able to search in lookup when using sforce.one.createRecord

Tags: lookup, create-records

I'm employing `sforce.one.createRecord("customObject", "{!jobRecordTypeID}", {!lightningPrepopulatedFields})` within one of my Visualforce pages. The `lightningPrepopulatedFields` are generated using JSON generator.

Upon returning to the record creation page, it displays the prepopulated lookup along with another field. However, if I attempt to remove the lookup and add a new value, it doesn't return anything. Moreover, the lookup doesn't even display the most recent values.

This issue persists across all lookup fields on the record creation page.
Sometimes, the functionality works seamlessly without any problems!!!